# Subgroup ArcPy list Query

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

Mornig, folks.

I have two equal sets of layers, disposed in subgroups in my ArcGIS Pro (2.9.0), as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vFP2.png).
It's important that they have the same name (Layer1, Layer2, ...) in both groups.
Now, I'm writing an ArcPy code that makes a Definition Query, but I want to do it only in one specific sub layer (Ex. Compare\Layer1 and Compare\Layer2).

For now, I have this piece of code that, I hope, can help.

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
m = p.listMaps()[0]
l = m.listLayers()

for row in l:
    print(row.name)

COD_QUERY = 123

for row in l:
    if row.name in ('Compare\Layer1'):
        row.definitionQuery = "CODIGO_EOL = {}".format(COD_QUERY)
        print('ok')
```

When I write **'Compare\layer1'** where's supposed to select only the Layer1 placed in the Compare group, the code doesn't work as expected and does the Query both in **Compare\Layer1** and **Base\Layer2**. That's the exact problem tha I'm having.

Hope I can find some help with u guys. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer's `name` (or `longName`) does not include the group layer's name.

Try using a [wildcard](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) (follow the link and search for `listLayers`) and filter for the particular group layer. A group layer object has a method `listLayers` too, you can again leverage it to get a specific layer.

```py
import arcpy

COD_QUERY = 123

project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
map = project.listMaps()[0]

filtered_group_layers = map.listLayers("Compare")

if filtered_group_layers and filtered_group_layers[0].isGroupLayer:

    filtered_layers = filtered_group_layers[0].listLayers("Layer1")

    if filtered_layers:

        filtered_layers[0].definitionQuery = f"CODIGO_EOL = {COD_QUERY}"
```

---

Or you can use loops. The key here is to filter out the group layers using `isGroupLayer` property before accessing the layer's `listLayers` method.

```py
import arcpy

COD_QUERY = 123

project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
map = project.listMaps()[0]

group_layers = (layer for layer in map.listLayers() if layer.isGroupLayer)

for group_layer in group_layers:

    if group_layer.name in "Compare":
        
        for layer in group_layer.listLayers():

            if layer.name in "Layer1":

                layer.definitionQuery = f"CODIGO_EOL = {COD_QUERY}"
```